# SAAS Multitenant app + connect different database issue

Tags: database, performance, multi-tenant, connection, multi-database

I'm developing a SAAS application using Laravel. I have one master database and multiple tenant databases. As I am a admin, i want to check tenants performance and tenant details. For Ex. Basecamp. I want to check how many accounts created in tenant app and how many projects registered and option to disable/enable users of tenant app.

My Idea is to view these tenant reports, i will connect/switch to tenant database only for these reports and do process. But if I'm having 1000 tenant means 1000 database need to connect to view all reports frequently. Is it a good process or any suggestion on how to implement it?